ESM cache get updated every 10 minutes
Ubuntu 20.04 throws logs almost 100k times per day for ESM cache update.
Can some one let me know, what exactly the ESM cache update does? And why does the ESM cache updated every 10-15 minutes. Its populating my Datadog with almost 100k logs per day
>Starting Update the local ESM caches...
>esm-cache.service: Succeeded.
>Finished Update the local ESM caches.

Yes there is way to mask this updates but is it a good option to mask those updates
